# finding element in map with list c++

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, stl, multimap

I have a multimap with an integer(x) and a list(list).

```
std::map<int,std::list<int> > my_map;
```

Say mylist1 consists of elements 100,200,300 and I map it to integer 1

mylist2 consists of elements 99,199,299 and I map it to integer 2

```
my_map.insert(pair<int,std::list<int> > (1, mylist1));
my_map.insert(pair<int,std::list<int> > (2, mylist2));
```

Now given an element say 200, how can i return the value 1(saying that element 200 belongs 
to a list that is mapped to integer element 1?

Comment: It's not a multimap when you declare it as `std::map<>`. It's just a normal map. Also, look up `make_pair()` for when inserting into a map.

Comment: Thanks fixing it. Also any idea about how to search for it?

Answer (score 4):

You should use elements of the lists as keys and an integer as value.
Given your example:

```
std::multimap<int, int> my_map;
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(100, 1));
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(200, 1));
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(300, 1));

my_map.insert(std::make_pair(99, 2));
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(199, 2));
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(299, 2));
```

then just use `std::multimap<int,int>::equal_range` function

Comment: The problem with this is this may not be very efficient hence I chose to use lists.

Comment: @codebreaker Not efficient how? You need to think about what is important for your data structure. In what way would multimap not be efficient? Why is and how is list more efficient for you. Without knowing the limitations of your problems there is no way you can get a good answer as how to do this efficiently for your case.

Comment: @codebreaker I don't agree with you. This kind of index will be efficient, because your type of queries will have logarithmic complexity from the number of distinct elements in your lists. If you just do brute-force search it is linear time. To me, it is better to build index once(spend linear time for populating map with data) and then have efficient searches.

Answer (score 1):

As @NirMH told - what was the problem just with iterating over the map ?
I assume you are using C++98 standard compiler. Here is the simple code for you (http://rextester.com/WVBE96570):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::list<int> > my_map;
    std::list<int> l1;
    l1.push_back(10);
    l1.push_back(20);

    std::list<int> l2;
    l2.push_back(30);
    l2.push_back(40);

    my_map[1] = l1;
    my_map[2] = l2;

    int value_to_find = 40;
    int list_index = -1;
    for(std::map<int, std::list<int> >::const_iterator p_int_list_pair = my_map.begin(),
        end = my_map.end(); p_int_list_pair != end; ++p_int_list_pair)
    {
        const int& curr_index = p_int_list_pair->first;
        const std::list<int>& curr_list = p_int_list_pair->second;
        std::list<int>::const_iterator curr_list_end = curr_list.end();
        if(std::find(curr_list.begin(), curr_list_end, value_to_find) != curr_list_end)
        {
            list_index = curr_index;
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << list_index;
}
```

Comment: Btw, it's not good idea to use map in your case. If you want use map - do as @nikitoz says

Comment: which other Data structure would you suggest?

Comment: In your case I think that the best idea is to use simple vector of pairs (std::vector<std::pair<std::list<int>, int > >). This will be simple and good anought.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-Code:

```
Iterate over my_map
   For every iteration, search the value (list<int>) for your target integer
   If found, return the my_map iterator first item
```

You can use the `find` method from `algorithm` header to optimize the search.

Comment: is there an example for that?

Comment: @codebreaker - example to what specifically? let me know what you seek

Answer (score 0):

Here's my C++11 take on it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using value_type = int;
using list_type = ::std::list<value_type>;
using key_type = int;
using map_type = ::std::map<key_type, list_type>;
using pair_type = map_type::value_type;


list_type my_list_1;
list_type my_list_2;
map_type my_map;


map_type::const_iterator find_key_of_first_list_containing (const value_type x, const map_type & map)
{
    auto map_cend = map.cend();
    for (auto map_cit = map.cbegin(); map_cit != map_cend; ++map_cit)
    {
        auto list = map_cit->second;
        auto list_cend = list.cend();
        auto list_cit = ::std::find(list.cbegin(), list_cend, x);
        if (list_cit != list_cend)
            return map_cit;
    }
    return map_cend;
}


int main (int, char **)
{
    my_list_1.push_back(100);
    my_list_1.push_back(200);
    my_list_1.push_back(300);

    my_list_2.push_back(99);
    my_list_2.push_back(199);
    my_list_2.push_back(299);

    my_map.insert(pair_type(1, my_list_1));
    my_map.insert(pair_type(2, my_list_2));

    auto i = find_key_of_first_list_containing(200, my_map);

    if (i != my_map.end())
        ::std::cout << "Found at: " << i->first << "\n";
    else
        ::std::cout << "Not found!\n";

    return 0;
}
```